# Indexing nested documents in Elasticsearch with same field names

Tags: elasticsearch

If I have a object of class `Car` that has an nested object of class `Engine` where both classes have the field named "id" do I have to do anything special when I create the mapping? Or is it sufficient to add the type "nested" to the engine mapping.

Elasticsearch head GUI is showing unexpected rows, but the search seems to give the correct result so it would be good to know if I need to do anything else in the mapping if two or more objects have the same field name.

Seems like the structured query builder returns the engine document with the id that I search for when I select `car.id` from the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn't be any problem, you can just use the dot notation to refer to the fields in the nested documents.

Also, if you have a single engine per car you don't need to declare the engine as nested in your mapping.